# My Jquery slider is working locally but not on Web Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, sliders

I've a test website on http://insstock.info/xxx/

With two sliders inserted into it:

1. Nivo Slider
2. DIV Content Jquery slider (Exact below of Nivo Slider)

second slider is expected to flip the content one by one; the code and scripts are set accordingly!

It is showing no error in Chrome developer tool Console panel!

Can anyone Please help me to making this second slider work?

Comment: How do you load second slider?

Comment: Line 23
<!-- Slider css -->
         <link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <!-- Slider Plugin End -->

Comment: I mean where is js/jquery code which initialize your element #contentslider ? I cannot find it in your code

Comment: Can you try to load your slider inside window.load function (like nivoslider) using var jQuerySlider=jQuery.jQuerySlider() instead of loading it in the included "js/jquery-slider.js"? I think it wont works because the dom is not ready when you execute the script.

Comment: Thanks Edward! for your suggestion. It works now!!!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions that I run through when I experience this behavior.

1) Clear the Chrome Cache

Chrome caches aggressively and frequently will return stale resources.  You can clear the cache either by using Ctrl+Shift+Del, or prevent its use on the page by opening up Chrome Developer tools, clicking the gear icon in the bottom right, and checking "Disable Cache".  Then reload the page with Ctrl+Shift+R.  This will ensure you have the latest version of your resources.

2) Check the Network tab for any resources which are failing to load

3) Step through your code in the debugger to try to identify where things go wrong.

4) Start removing pieces more and more pieces of your code until you have a very small set that is exhibiting the issue.  This is a great strategy for debugging generally, since it is much easier to debug something small than something big.

Comment: It works with  Window.onload event

Thank you for your effort!